# Multiple Imputation package of R smcfcs

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to use the R package `smcfcs` and command smcfcs.

CRAN:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smcfcs/smcfcs.pdf

Examples are as follows.

```
imps <- smcfcs(ex_linquad, smtype="lm", smformula="y~z+x+xsq",
method=c("","","norm","x^2",""))

imps <- smcfcs(ex_coxquad, smtype="coxph", smformula="Surv(t,d)~z+x+xsq",
method=c("","","","norm","x^2",""))
```

I cannot understand "method".
Does it means the type of explanatory or explained variables?
y and z is no type and x is norm type and xsq means squared type?
logreg means 0 or 1 ?
What does the mean of last ""?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't read the documentation's description of that argument. Could you try reading that first, and then maybe explain what you still don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically all information you request is already in the documentation.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smcfcs/smcfcs.pdf

For function **smcfcs**, parameter **method** you get the following information:

> **method**: A required vector of strings specifying for each variable either that
>   it does not need to be imputed (""), the type of regression model to
>   be be used to impute. Possible values are "norm" (normal linear
>   regression), "logreg" (logistic regression), "poisson" (Poisson
>   regression), "podds" (proportional odds regression for ordered
>   categorical variables), "mlogit" (multinomial logistic regression for
>   unordered categorical variables), or a custom expression which defines
>   a passively imputed variable, e.g. "x^2" or "x1*x2".

This means for the example:

```
imps <- smcfcs(ex_linquad, smtype="lm", smformula="y~z+x+xsq",
method=c("","","norm","x^2",""))
```

ex_linquad is the dataset that shall be imputed (comes with smcfcs package)

This dataset has 5 variables.

Accoring to the documentation method=c("","","norm","x^2","") means:

- Variable 1 wont be imputed:   ""
- Variable 2 wont be imputed:   ""
- For Variable 3 normal linear regression will be used:  norm
- For Variable 4 a custom expression is used:   x^2
- Variable 5 wont be imputed:  ""